# How to get the constructor argument in computed property

Tags: android, kotlin, computed-properties

I wrap the `sharedPreference` object into viewModel.

```
class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    application: Application,
    myPreferences: MyPreference
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }

    private val _something: String
        get() = myPreferences.getStoredSomething(getApplication()) // But myPreferences can not be used in this line.
    val something = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

How to fix the scope of `myPreferences` to reach the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare class properties in the primary constructor by using `val` or `var` and optionally add an access modifier. It will make your constructor arguments became properties and they will be available in your class as if you would declare them near `private val viewModelJob...` property.

Here is an example with modified primary constructor where it's arguments declared as `private val`. Now they are visible throughout the whole scope of this class.

```
class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val application: Application,
    private val myPreferences: MyPreference
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    ... 

    private val _something: String
        get() = myPreferences.getStoredSomething(getApplication())

    val something = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

The official example of this particular feature ([source link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)):

> ... for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax:
>
> ```
> class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int) { /*...*/ }
> ```